# Python 3.5 - "Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I added geckodriver.exe into PATH as you can see on [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2yXP.png)
and i restarted my computer after. But the error still show up.

Here's my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
```

Do you have clues about what I did wrong ?

Comment: Would you mind posting the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Comment: In windows, Create Enviroment variable "webdriver.gecko.driver" and set the driver path("c:\geckodriver.exe") as value.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to resolve this error.

1. Download the gecko driver and keep it in directory where your python test script is there.
2. Set the environment variable "webdriver.gecko.driver" with driver path as value. `os.environ["webdriver.gecko.driver"]="c:\geckodriver.exe"`
3. Pass executable path to the constructor like `driver = WebDriver.Firefox("path of executable")`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any significant error in your code block.
While working with Selenium 3.4.3, geckodriver v0.17.0, Mozilla Firefox 53.0 with Python 3.6.1 you can consider  downloading the geckodriver and save it anywhere in your machine and configuring the absolute path of the geckodriver through `executable_path`.

> It is to be noted that the current Selenium-Python binding is unstable with geckodriver and looks to be Architecture specific. You can find the github [discussion](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3884) and [merge](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/pull/685) here. So you may additionally need to pass the absolute path of the firefox binary as `firefox_binary` argument while initializing the **webdriver**

Here is your own code block which executes well at my end:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it says now : "WebDriverException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities"

Comment: @Hobsido Can you consider ensuring that you have provided the correct absolute path of `firefox.exe` and `geckodriver.exe`? Which system are you using Linux or Windows? Thanks

Comment: i work on Windows and i checked : both path are correct

Comment: @@Hobsido What is your Selenium, geckodriver & Mozilla Firefox versions? Thanks

Comment: Mozilla Firefox 51.0.1 / Geckodriver 0.17.0 / Selenium 3.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the capabilities correctly? In case you are setting the version capability, verify that it is correct or remove it altogether. I am talking of the below:

```
capabilities.SetCapability("version", "50.0");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 it can be solved after replacing Firefox driver with chrome driver.
`driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

**Download Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019**
https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x86.exe OR https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe and install based on your Operating system.

**Download Chrome Driver** from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/ based on your operating system.

Add chrome drivers in your PATH