# WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) with GeckoDriver Firefox and Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

Using Selenium 3.1.0, firefox latest version 72.0, default firefox driver 2.53.1
  here is my code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver" ,"C:\\Users\\sindhusha.tummala\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Still i am getting the error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055;
```

Could any one help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055;
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** binary (executable) was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Firefox Browser** session as it was unable to locate the FirefoxBinary.

This issue arises when *Firefox* is not installed at the default location or is not installed at all.

---

### Solution

To solve this issue:

- If *Firefox* is not al all installed you have to install it.
- If *Firefox* is not installed at the default location you need to pass the *absolute path* of the *Firefox* binary through the argument `firefox_binary` as follows:
- Code block:

  ```
  public class A_Firefox_binary 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver.exe");
          FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
          options.setBinary("C:\\path\\to\\firefox.exe");
          WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(options);
          driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
          System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```

---

### Additional Consideration

Ensure that:

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u222**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.141.59**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.26.0**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0) level.
- GeckoDriver is present in the desired location.
- GeckoDriver is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v70.0*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### Outro

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to open Firefox Developer Edition through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754686/how-to-open-firefox-developer-edition-through-selenium/54762442#54762442)
- [Python 3.5 - “Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44631020/python-3-5-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path/44632206#44632206)

Comment: Still ia m getting the same error, using gecko 0.26.0

Comment: @sindhu Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:   got this

Comment: @sindhu So your initial error of _...Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary..._ is resolved. Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?